# How can I see a preview image in flask

Tags: python, image, flask, sqlalchemy

I saved photos in sqlaclmechy and I want thath I can see a preview of the photo (like in the image) and also when I click on it the image open.

[image]

```
class FileContent(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'four'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    client_name = db.Column(db.String)
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    comments = db.Column(db.String(100)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files['image']
        comentaries = request.form['comentaries']

        if not allowed_image(file.filename):
            return('No valid extencion')
        else: 
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

        newFile = FileContent(client_name=current_user.username, comments=comentaries, data=file.read())
        db.session.add(newFile)
        db.session.commit() 
        return 'Saved ' + file.filename + ' to the database'
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

Comment: This platform lives from the fact that there are volunteers who are willing to sacrifice their time and use their knowledge to help others to solve their problems. In order to give these people feedback on the success of their measures, the users are given a wide variety of means. It would be nice if the questioner would use this to rate the answer and / or mark the question as answered. Even if you have received an answer, it is always possible to clarify any resulting ambiguities with comments. I hope that you understand my concerns and thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should meet your requirements. Maybe you should only allow
one mimetype or add it to the database as well.

```
from flask import abort, send_file
import io

@app.route('/<int:id>')
def show(id):
    file_content = FileContent.query.get_or_404(id)

    # Test here whether data is set or define the database column as non-nullable.
    if not file_content.data:
        abort(404)

    # Please define a mime type here. Otherwise the data will be downloaded as a file.
    return send_file(
        io.BytesIO(file_content.data),
        mimetype='image/jpeg'
    )
```

```
<a href="{{ url_for('show', id=file_content_id) }}">
    <img src="{{ url_for('show', id=file_content_id) }}" />
</a>
```